# how to take only property name and ignore its values in powershell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have a properties file, in which one of the property looks like this

```
tls.default.cipherSuites = TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                           TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                           TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

I wanted to display only property name but not its values. I tried below command

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\run_pa.properties" |
  Where-Object { ! $_.StartsWith("#") } |
    ? { $_.trim() -ne "" } | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '=.*' }
```

but i'm getting output as below

```
tls.default.protocols 
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,\
                       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
                       TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

How to avoid property values for this scenario and get only property name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following filters the lines down to those that do not start with `#` and contain a `=`, and then removes everything starting with optional whitespace before the `=` from them, which leaves just the property names:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Test\run_pa.properties") -notmatch '^#' -match '=' -replace '\s*=.*'
```

Comment: Works perfect. Earlier i tried  Where-Object { $_ -match("=") } with my query but i didn't filter out complete property name.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-Raw` option on `Get-Content` to always get just one `string` (there are version differences between v4 and v5) instead of an array for each line. Then just split it by the `=` sign and trim out whitespace using `.Trim(' ')`:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw
$propertyName = $content .Split('=')[0].Trim(' ')
```

Comment: Your solution works with the single-property sample input, but the real input has _multiple_ properties (it's a _properties_ file; the sample input is just the _one_ property that's problematic).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta